# How were the culprits "dragged to their death"?

Tags: danganronpa

After a student is found guilty, the next scene if of them being tied up or trapped in a new room before dying an "interesting" death.

But who put them there? Does the anime ever give any indication of who is tying up the guilty and dragging them to the "death room"?

See this video for example (Ep3): https://youtu.be/um_HQ6XyzLQ?t=17m
The culprit is found guilty and shortly after Monokuma pushes the red button, he is instantly "teleported" to a room to die. How?

I hope this question makes sense. I couldn't figure out how to word it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anime series itself shows quite clearly that it is **Monokuma**.

He is only seen actually dragging the culprit himself in the gameplay-looking animation, but there's no reason to doubt that that's exactly what happens, particulary when it is consistent with the argument.

The following images are taken from the same episode you use as an example.

[image]

[image]

[image: d]

[image]

Comment: [Spoiler] But we know Monokuma is a tiny robotic bear. How could he have the strength to drag a high school student like this?

Comment: [Spoiler] Quoting from [danganronpa.wikia](http://danganronpa.wikia.com/wiki/Monokuma), "In Ultra Despair Girls, it's revealed that Monokumas were originally a series of larger killing machines"

Comment: So I don't see a reason for Monokuma not to be able to drag someone like that. He is often portrayed comically, but he still is a small version of a killing robot!

Comment: you know your stuff! I also found an [answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27302/why-is-the-monokuma-eye-in-the-school-crest) that states Monokuma was actually made as a life-saving robot so I guess he's more than just a toy.

Comment: Monokuma is also able to fight Sakura Oogami on more-or-less even terms, so he's hardly weak.